# How to delete a user account on a Stack exchange site?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I want to delete my account on this site. How to can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

From the [help page](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/) you will find ["How do I delete my account?"](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account) under the *My Account* section.

Follow the steps described there.  After confirming that you've read what account deletion entails (it's **permanent**, for one thing), you'll be able to hit the "Delete Profile" button.

Once you do that, one of two things will happen:

1. Your account will be immediately deleted if you've never posted or voted more than once.
2. Otherwise, your account will be scheduled for deletion.  You'll have the opportunity to cancel the deletion for 24 hours, but after that, it's gone.

---

[You can learn more on the official SE FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account).